# Whats wrong with this lambda expression?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller

"file" is a Mono object received from RestController, I want to convert it into byte[]

```
byte[] bytes=file.map(filePart -> filePart.content().map(dataBuffer -> dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().array()}));
```

it says no instance to variable R exist so that it conforms byte[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for starters that `}` near the end makes this not compile!
But also, if file is a Mono, then map will also return a Mono, you will need to `.block()` to get out a value out.

and then you probably want to figure out how to get rid of that block again, if you really want to do reactive.